# How to code a residual between cells test after a contrast test?

Tags: stata, anova, contrast

I'm doing a contrast test in Stata and would like to do a residual between-cells variation test after the contrast test, but cannot yet figure out how to code this. Other researchers doing this test typically report the F-value and p-value for the residuals, which then should be insignficant to show good fit of the contrast.

The contrast code looks like this:

`anova DV IV1##IV2`

`contrast {IV1#IV2 -1 -1 -1 3}`

I tried taking the residuals of the contrast test, but that is not possible .